# An apocalypse manhwa where the world is destroyed by monsters and there is snow

Tags: story-identification, manga

The manhwa begins with the protagonist getting supplies from a store covered in snow, and he comes out with some supplies in the middle of the blizzard with his dog and then is attacked by monsters that are faster than him and almost catch him alone. That his dog fights against them and the boy fights with his dog.

I read it over a month ago and I don't remember the website.
it is full color.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/tips-for-asking-story-identification-questions) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: "Subway Line 1" has some snow in the first chapter, but it's definitely not a blizzard, and I don't see a dog. Guessing that's not it.